# Making a clickable table data

Tags: jquery, html-table

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>click</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

How to make just the `<td>click</td>` clickable and when the user clicks there, some information will be displayed on other `<td></td>` (empty td) using jquery?

Comment: `some information will be displayed on other (empty td) using jquery` to which one ?

Comment: there are 1 td with name click and other 5 td with no content . but when that click is clicked ,the information should be visible on that 5 empty td.

Comment: Please once check my sites on http://tushantkhatiwada.com.np/back2design/index.html . I want all the button(i.e Sponsored , History Contests , CFB Contests , Last Man Standing Blits Fire Tacos) be clickable and each will populate different information on their corresponding row (Pick 
Deadline,play,results,leaderboards,prizes) but i could only display the information but could not hide the information when it is again clicked on the same button of corresponding row . Sorry for my bad english .

Answer (score 0):

in some

```
$(function(){
$('td').click(function(){
    $('td').next().text('void');
});
});
```

```js
$(function(){
$('td').click(function(){
    $(this).next().text('next');
})
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>click</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks . I understood it clearly . Now if i want every table data to have different text than i should give them a class and instead of 'td' i have to use '.classname'.

Comment: in Jquery is `addClass('youClassNew');`

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this:

```js
$(function(){
    $('table tr > td:first').on('click', function() {
        $(this).nextAll().text('Information...');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>click</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Also, if you can put an `id/class` in your table then it would be like this:

```
// Using "mytable" as class/for id, use #mytable
$(function(){
    $('table.mytable tr > td:first').on('click', function() {
        $(this).nextAll().text('Information...');
    });
});
```

Comment: I think this will populate the same information on each 'td' .

Comment: Yes. In this case you need to dynamically provide the value and you didn't provide enough info before.

Comment: Please once check my sites on tushantkhatiwada.com.np/back2design/index.html . I want all the button(i.e Sponsored , History Contests , CFB Contests , Last Man Standing Blits Fire Tacos) be clickable and each will populate different information on their corresponding row (Pick Deadline,play,results,leaderboards,prizes) but i could only display the information but could not hide the information when it is again clicked on the same button of corresponding row . Sorry for my bad english